# Why am I getting a mkdir error with this sudo mkdir /var/www/magento-dev.local/public command?

Tags: command-line, server, apache2, magento

I'm trying to install Magento on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. I created a file called `magento-dev.local` in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` directory. that has the following contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 # ServerName (domain) and admin email
 ServerAdmin webmaster@magento-dev.local
 ServerName magento-dev.local

 # Folder of this site. This is required.
 DocumentRoot /var/www/magento-dev.local/public 

 # Log file locations
 LogLevel warn
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/magento-dev.error.log
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/magento-dev.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I get the following error when I try and run this command:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/www/magento-dev.local/public
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www/magento-dev.local/public': No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: does magento-dev.local exist?

Comment: why do I have to use -p?

Thank you for the response!

Comment: use `sudo mkdir -p /var/www/magento-dev.local/public`

Comment: this `-p` create parent directory if it doesn't exits

Comment: Does the magento-dev.local exist? 

Yes I created a file called magento-dev.local in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/ directory

Comment: Merely making a configuration file for apache doesn't create the directories.

Comment: but you are getting problem in `/var/www/magento-dev.local/public` directory. see [@muru answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/530242/146791).

Comment: @user21839 a file or a directory? file is wrong ;)

Answer (score 3):

`mkdir` will fail if any directory in the given path (except the last) doesn't exist. Use the `-p` option to tell it to make such directories automatically:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/magento-dev.local/public
```

Be warned that this can create problems if you made a typo:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/magento-deva.local/public
```

**This will create a `magento-deva.local` directory and a `public` directory in it.**
Always double check your paths if you use `-p`.

From [`man mkdir`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mkdir.1.html):

```
-p, --parents
      no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Comment: I have a follow up question. Now after running $ sudo mkdir -p /var/www/magento-dev.local/public and $ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magento-dev.local I try to run the command $ sudo a2ensite magento-dev.local and I get the following error "ERROR: Site magento-dev.local does not exist!" As the question indicates the file does exist!!!

Comment: @user21839 in apache 2.4, site configuration files are supposed to have a `.conf` extension.

Comment: so the file created in /etc/apache2/sites-available directory should be called magento-dev.local.conf and the command should be sudo a2ensite magento-dev.local.conf?

Comment: @user21839 yep. You might also need to correct some options in the configuration, but that's a whole new question.